# Regular Expression Lookbehind doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in .net.

```
<p class='p1'>Para 1</p><p>Para 2</p><p class="p2">Para 3</p><p>Para 4</p>
```

Now, I want to get only text inside the tag p (Para 1, Para 2, Para 3, Para4).

I used the following regular expression but it doesn't give me expected result.

```
(?<=<p.*>).*?(?=</p>)
```

If I use `(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)` it will give Para 2 and Para 4 which both p tags doesn't have class attribute?

I'd like to know what's wrong with `(?<=<p.*>).*?(?=</p>)` that code.

Comment: Looks to me like you're parsing HTML with regex. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (Best viewed in browser which supports unicode :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's illustrate this using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com):

[image: RegexBuddy Screenshot]

Your regex matches more than you think - the dot matches any character, so it doesn't care about tag boundaries.

What it is actually doing:

- `(?<=<p.*>)`: Assert that there is `<p` (followed by any number of characters) *anywhere* in the string before the current position, followed by a `>`.
- `.*?`: Match any number of characters...
- `(?=</p>)`: ...until the next occurence of `</p>`.

Your question is a bit unclear, but if your plan is to find text within `<p>` tags regardless of whether they contain any attributes, you shouldn't be using regular expressions anyway but a DOM parser, for example the [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

That said, if you insist on a regex, try

```
(?<=<p[^<>]*>)(?:(?!</p>).)*
```

[image: Another screenshot]

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=<p[^<>]*>)  # Assert position right after a p tag
(?:(?!</p>).)*  # Match any number of characters until the next </p>
```

Comment: I think his requirement is to match and find the text inside the paragraph tag regardless of whether they contain a class or any other attribute. Either way, he's better off using something like HTML Agility pack :)

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the code to (?<=<p.*?>).*?(?=</p>) by adding ? in the lookbehind making it optional. But it seems like it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @lilmaster: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? The lookbehind is useless in its current form anyway, it doesn't matter if you make it optional. I've just added an explanation why this is so.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I want to get the text between each p tags. It's my goal. If I use (?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>), it will return text between p tags without class attribute. But in my case, I want to get text between p tags with or without class attribute.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It works great. Thanks for your help. I've to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using following expression?

```
<p[\s\S]*?>(?<text_inside_p>[\s\S]*?)</p>
```

group named `text_inside_p` will contain desired text.

Comment: out of interest does [\s\S] omit things that . would include?

Comment: `[\s\S]` matches any character - whitespace | non-whitespace. So will include linebreaks etc... Though in C# regex in multiline mode I think `.` will match newline anyway... Though I may be wrong.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: you're right about .NET, except it's `Singleline` mode that beefs up the dot, not `Multiline`.